# Orbeon calendar behavior

Tags: calendar, orbeon

when using a calendar (input with a bind to a date), is there a way to control the interpretation of the input ?

For what I've seen:

- 1-31 will be the nth of the current month
- 32-99 is n day after the first of the current month
- x0y is the yth day of xth month of the current year
- Then it's a little random

511950 will give 05/01/2050
but 151950 will give 01/05/2050

From what i gathered, the control tries to interpret some symbols (any symbol, this includes digits) as separators.

So for example, 151950 is 1/1/50 instead of 1/5/1950 and because it's more than 50 years, the '50' is translated as 2050 instead of 1950.

This is pretty confusing for users, specially when they explicitly put the year with 4 digits and not only 2.

So i'm looking for a way to be a lot stricter. For instance only allowing the dd/mm/yyyy format (with explicit separators). The rest would render the value invalid instead of trying to translate it in something it is not.

Is there a way to do that ?

We're using Orbeon 3.8, and our forms are mostly in french, so dd/mm order.

Comment: It does seem that the behavior is a bit funny. But why would you use why would you enter a string like 511950? You mean the user would have entered this by mistake right?

Comment: I totally agree with you, this is totally strange. It probably comes from users habits on a previous interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing is done with regular expressions. See [the code here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/223b6a91087272c65509afcb1860d224fce5acda/src/resources-packaged/ops/javascript/xforms.js#L696). (To be fair: this code is old!)

I suspect that the overflow conditions are simply a product of the JavaScript date object.

The only way to change this behavior as far as I know is to change the JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks. i wouldn't have known where to find it, but with that I just have to use more restrictive regexes. That should do it.

Comment: Great! And feel free to let us know your solution on the Orbeon forum.